# What are the requirements for using Google's GEvent?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, google

For a current project, we need to know when a Google map is done loading all of its tiles. I found the following question, which was for the same basic problem: [register event "loadend" on layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/register-event-loadend-on-layer)

So now, we're using the code from that answer:

```
GEvent.addListener(mGoogleHybridLayer.mapObject, "tilesloaded", function() {
 console.log("Tiles loaded");
});
```

However, this gives a reference error for `GEvent`. Are there some extra requirements for using `GEvent`? Do we need to import it from somewhere?

I can't post code we're using, because there isn't any yet - even in the browser's debug console, `GEvent` is undefined.

Using Openlayers 2.11.

EDIT: maybe I should restate the question into one that can actually be answered: what are all the requirements for being able to use GEvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a Gmap layer with openlayers through *mapObject*. 
See [that example](http://www.empreinte-urbaine.eu/mapping/styled_gmap.html) (and source code), which gives the ability to use gmap style.

You can try to access [events](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html) through *mapObject*. Never tested.

By the way, the example I pointed out uses the version 3 of gmaps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the resources! For the interested, the syntax goes like so:

google.maps.event.addListener(myLayer.mapObject,'zoom_changed',function() { /*whatever*/ });

... assuming your event is 'zoom_changed' and your layer is myLayer